# Is there a way in pytest to get rid of the "x tests ran in 0.01s" line in the output?

Tags: pytest

I have a usecase in which I use pytest to go over each file and just collect some metadata specific for my tests. I would like to use the output in another tool without having to manually remove the `=== no tests ran in 0.10s ===` line from the bottom of the output.

I have tried adding multiple quiet options and --no-summary but neither of them removes this.

I have noticed that if i use *--collect-only* with *-qq* this makes it disappear. I thought I could just use this but reading through documentation I haven't found a way to trigger the collect-only behavior other than using:

```py
def pytest_configure(config) -> None:
    if config.option.collect_metadata:
        config.addinivalue_line("addopts", "--collect-only")
```

but that doesn't seem to work either.

Is there a way to get rid of all the summary lines including `=== no tests ran in 0.10s ===` without writing my own test collector?

Comment: usually if you want structured output you'd use `--junit-xml` rather than trying to parse the console output (the console output is not intended for machine consumption)